# ExtJS 5 create dynamic panel from object

Tags: extjs, panel

lets say I have object

```
var obj = {
  xtype: 'panel',
  title: 'other panel'    
}
```

And I want to get dynamic panel from it. 
I want something like this:

```
var obj = {
      xtype: 'panel',
      title: 'other panel'    
    }
var panel = Ext.create(obj); //not work of course
```

and then bind event

```
panel.on('added', function(){console.log('hello world'});
```

how It possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Ext.widget` instead, like:

```
var panel = Ext.widget(obj.xtype, obj);
```